# Serial device (/dev/serial/) not showing up on Android

Tags: kernel, usb, android, serial-console

Trying to connect a serial device (3d printer) through the USB port in order to communicate with it (klipper firmware) on an Android device (LOS 18.1/Android 11, 3.18 kernel). But I can't find it in /dev/serial/, it only shows up as /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/bus/usb/001/00[^1] and I can't communicate with it through those. I've compiled the kernel with the ch341.c driver. 'lsusb -v' from a chrooted Debian through Linux deploy gives the following output, the device in question is called 'QinHeng Electronics CH340...':

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         3
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            3.18
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 3.18.140-Swan-gcb3e40e597b0-dirty xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 xhci-hcd.0.auto
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x001f
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              12
  bDescriptorType      42
  nNbrPorts             1
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
  wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x000f
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x02
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   3
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           0 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat           0 micro seconds
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x1a86 QinHeng Electronics
  idProduct          0x7523 CH340 serial converter
  bcdDevice            2.64
  iManufacturer           0
  iProduct                2 USB Serial
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0027
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower               98mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      1
      bInterfaceProtocol      2
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               1
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            3.18
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 3.18.140-Swan-gcb3e40e597b0-dirty xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 xhci-hcd.0.auto
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength               9
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts             1
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0103 power enable connect
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

How can I communicate with the serial device? Are there any other kernel modules I should compile? Does newer Android handle serial devices in a different way than Linux does? I've seen other people run this firmware on Android in chrooted Linux like [here](https://github.com/sanjy666/klipper-tablet), [here](https://gist.github.com/CODeRUS/a5ec4a456f5b58186cbebb66a8542a2e), [here](https://all3dprint.blogspot.com/2020/09/klipper-on-android-galaxy-s3-ender-3-pro.html). So it is possible, I just must be missing something. I'm happy to post other debugging information/logs.

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/ttyUSB0` would be the Linux kernel default name for most USB-to-serial converters, while `/dev/serial/*` is probably an alias created by some udev rule. If your Android system has a minimized set of ude rules, it might not include the rule to generate the `/dev/serial/*` aliases.

The `/dev/ttyUSB0` (and any aliases for it, if they exist) is a Unix TTY device interface (basically a serial port + a lot of optional features for dealing with archaic serial terminals) for the USB-to-serial converter. If there is an actual RS-232 serial communication between the converter chip and the actual 3d printer, you might need to set the correct serial port parameters before you can communicate successfully. Even a minimal terminal emulator program such as `picocom` might help a lot here, although you probably can use `stty` to make the settings if you have to.

The `/dev/bus/usb/*/*` devices, on the other hand, expect the program using them to be aware of the functionality of the USB bus. In practice, a program would most likely use the `libusb` library to deal with those devices.